# composer network install command gives error as Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am using Hyperledger Composer version v0.19.9 and Hyperledger Fabric version v1.1.

I have setup my blockchain network using Fabric and made all docker containers up and running. Following docker containers are running:

```
1. cli
2. orderer.sterlite.com
3. peer0.orga.sterlite.com
4. ca.orga.sterlite.com
5. peer0.orgb.sterlite.com
```

I have created a Peer Admin card using Composer CLI named `PeerAdminOrgA@sterlite`.

Now, when I try to install a business network using below command, I am getting an error:

```
composer network install -c PeerAdminOrgA@sterlite -a com-fab-bn.bna
```

Following is the error:

```
    safvan@safvan-VirtualBox:~/blockchain/fabric-sdk/fabric-sdk-go/src/github.com/sterliteChain/config$ composer network install -c PeerAdminOrgA@sterlite -a com-fab-bn.bna
    Installing business network. This may take a minute...
    Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
    Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF
    Command failed
```

Following is the outcome of docker ps command:

```
safvan@safvan-VirtualBox:~/blockchain/fabric-sdk/fabric-sdk-go/src/github.com/sterliteChain/config$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
3645759c804d        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"              About a minute ago   Up About a minute                                                    cli
7f72016afeef        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"                19 hours ago         Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.sterlite.com
74f6a3c3f493        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        19 hours ago         Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.orga.sterlite.com
6c3ab687ec95        hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-seâ¦"   19 hours ago         Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.orga.sterlite.com
c6187a82e300        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        19 hours ago         Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp   peer0.orgb.sterlite.com
```

Kindly help me fix this issue.

Comment: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF error is a failure of Composer to connect to the Fabric, one assumes all of the Fabric nodes have started (you could post `docker  ps` showing what's running). Are you using TLS connections? Have you got grpc or grpcs defined in your connection profile..

Comment: I have verified all docker containers are up and running using docker ps command. I am using grpc in my connection profile.

Comment: what addresses are you using in the connection.json for the URLs ?